# NullReferenceException: Threading in a .NET structure?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, structure, dispatcher

Whenever I call the constructor of the following `Structure` (*with the parameter set to* `True`) I get a NullReferenceException:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Public Structure Test

  Private MyDispatcher As Dispatcher
  Private MyResetEvent As ManualResetEvent

  Public Sub New(ByVal newThread As Boolean)
    If newThread Then
      MyResetEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
      Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf Start)
      thread.Start()
      MyResetEvent .WaitOne()

      ' NullReferenceException below:
      MyDispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf DoSomething))
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Start()
    MyDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
    MyResetEvent.Set()
    Dispatcher.Run()
  End Sub

  Private Sub DoSomething()
  End Sub
End Structure
```

`MyDispatcher` is `Nothing`, which causes the NullReferenceException. But using a `Class` instead of a `Structure` works just fine. Why?

**Edit**: And what workarounds are possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the delegate that is constructed when you use `AddressOf`. Delegates are constructed using an `Object` reference (for instance methods). The structure, necessarily, is boxed when it is passed as an `Object`, and will be unboxed before `Start` is called. It is this second, unboxed, *copy* of your structure that the `Start` method mutates.

Your original code, still working with the unboxed original structure, will see no modifications.

Comment: If the `Start` method mutates a second structure, why does the first structure's `ManualResetEvent` receive the signal that `Start` sends?

Comment: Because a "*ResetEvent" is internally a handle, which refers to something else. So you're duplicating the handle, but not the object it refers to.

Comment: @RuudLenders - because `MyResetEvent` is a reference. The boxed and unboxed copy of the structure contains a *copy* of this reference. Both *references* refer to the same object.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So if I understand you correctly, if I had multiple instances of my structure, their `MyResetEvent` would all refer to the same object?

Comment: @RuudLenders - or, to put it another way, try swapping the lines that create/assign to `MyResetEvent` and `thread` and you should now get a null reference exception inside `Start` when it tries to access `MyResetEvent`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - ah, now I understand it.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking another question, but do you happen to know any good workarounds for this behaviour?

Comment: @RuudLenders - well, the simple and obvious one is the one you've already included in your question - make it a `Class` instead of a `Structure`.